# Remove namespace tag in web service response using Spring-WS and Jaxb

Tags: java, web-services, soap, jaxb, spring-ws

I'm using a endpoint SOAP created On Spring Framework using JAXB, but I want that my anwers(Expected Response) return without prefix when I Send Request One, but this is returned like is showed on Current Response:.

How can I do to return a message SOAP without namespaces?

Request One

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"     xmlns:urn="urn:sap-com:document:sap:soap:functions:mc-style">
<soapenv:Header/>
<soapenv:Body>
<urn:ZProveerDatosPagoProveed2>
    <Bukrs>RG10</Bukrs>
    <Langu>S</Langu>
    <Lifnr>00000000</Lifnr>
</urn:ZProveerDatosPagoProveed2>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Current Response:

```
<soap-env:Envelope xmlns:soap-env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soap-env:Header/>
<soap-env:Body>
<n0:ZProveerDatosPagoProveed2Response xmlns:n0="urn:sap-com:document:sap:soap:functions:mc-style">
    <Adrnr>0000</Adrnr>
    <Bankk>0000</Bankk>
    <Bankn>0000</Bankn>
    <Bkont>0000</Bkont>
    <Iban>ES0000</Iban>
    <KoinhFi>ROBLES AVN</KoinhFi>
    <Land1>TH</Land1>
    <Landx>XXXXX</Landx>
    <Name1>ROBLES AVN</Name1>
    <Pstlz>0000</Pstlz>
    <Stcd1>A0000</Stcd1>
    <Stras>ROBLES AVN</Stras>
    <Swift>XXXXX</Swift>
    <Text1_052>ROBLES AVN</Text1_052>
    <Zterm>Z000</Zterm>
</n0:ZProveerDatosPagoProveed2Response>
</soap-env:Body>
</soap-env:Envelope>
```

Request one and the current response, are the request/response of a web service embedded in another web service (which I implemented), the reason for this implementation is that it has requested that the final answer is this (without namespaces tags):

Expected Response

```
<soap-env:Envelope xmlns:soap-env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soap-env:Header/>
<soap-env:Body>
 <ZProveerDatosPagoProveed2Response xmlns="urn:sap-com:document:sap:soap:functions:mc-style">
     <Adrnr>0000</Adrnr>
     <Bankk>0000</Bankk>
     <Bankn>0000</Bankn>
     <Bkont>0000</Bkont>
     <Iban>ES0000</Iban>
     <KoinhFi>ROBLES AVN</KoinhFi>
     <Land1>TH</Land1>
     <Landx>XXXXX</Landx>
     <Name1>ROBLES AVN</Name1>
     <Pstlz>0000</Pstlz>
     <Stcd1>A0000</Stcd1>
     <Stras>ROBLES AVN</Stras>
     <Swift>XXXXX</Swift>
     <Text1_052>ROBLES AVN</Text1_052>
     <Zterm>Z000</Zterm>
 </ZProveerDatosPagoProveed2Response>
</soap-env:Body>
</soap-env:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 0):

The way I was able to do it is the following:

1. Include the two following jars from [JAXB](https://jaxb.java.net/) : jaxb-core.jar and jaxb-impl.jar
2. In the package-info.java file, set the following settings:

Supposing your namespace is "**yournamespace**"

```
@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema(namespace = yournamespace, 
xmlns = {@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNs(prefix = "", 
namespaceURI = yournamespace)},
elementFormDefault = javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED,
attributeFormDefault = javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm.UNSET)
package com.ctpayment.admin;
```

It seems that the current implementation of java ignore the previous settings but the jaxb jars do not. I did not push my investigation further. Last but not least, you need the two jars in order to compile.